# How to remove MPRemoteCommandCenter from Notification Center

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

How to remove `MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()` from Notification Center. I tried this code, but only commands and actions are disabling. I need complete notification to be removed from the Notification Center. When we kill app it doesn't appear in notification bar, I want the same thing to be done when I move to other screen.

```
func removeCommanCenter() {

let commadCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
    commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
    commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = false
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = false
    commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.isEnabled = false

    commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.loadNextVideos))
    commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.loadPrevoiusVideos))
    commandCenter.playCommand.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.audioPlayerView.customPlayer?.togglePlay(_:)))
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.audioPlayerView.customPlayer?.togglePlay(_:)))
    commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.audioPlayerView.customPlayer?.handleChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent(event:)))
}
```

Comment: What is a notification bar?

Comment: @matt, Modified the question - it's Notification Center/Lock Screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It disappears from Notification Center, if we use `endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()`

Comment: As for `removeTarget(_:)` the documentation says: [specify nil to remove all targets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommand/1622903-removetarget#:~:text=The%20object%20that%20currently%20is%20a%20recipient%20of%20action%20messages%20sent%20by%20this%20object.%20Specify%20nil%20to%20remove%20all%20targets). By doing that I'm able to make it disappear from the notification center.
`endReceivingRemoteControlEvents()` didn't help though.